# Slow static IP assignment to Kubernetes Load Balancer on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: networking, ip-address, load-balancing, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes

When I create a Kubernetes Load Balancer Service using the following specification:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "a1"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "a1"
        },
        "ports": [
            {
                "port": 80,
                "targetPort": 80,
                "name": "http"
            },
            {
                "port": 443,
                "targetPort": 443,
                "name": "https"
            }
        ],
        "type": "LoadBalancer"
    }
}
```

I have to wait between 1 and 2 minutes until I get an `EXTERNAL_IP`.

I thought of reserving static IPs before and assigning them on Service creation:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Service",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "a1"
    },
    "spec": {
        "selector": {
            "app": "a1"
        },
        "ports": [
            {
                "port": 80,
                "targetPort": 80,
                "name": "http"
            },
            {
                "port": 443,
                "targetPort": 443,
                "name": "https"
            }
        ],
        "type": "LoadBalancer",
        "loadBalancerIP": "130.211.64.237"
    }
}
```

But I have the same delay 1 - 1.5 minutes:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME             CLUSTER_IP       EXTERNAL_IP      PORT(S)          SELECTOR             AGE
a1               10.127.248.248   130.211.64.237   80/TCP,443/TCP   app=a1               1m
```

Does anyone know why this delay happens and if there is a way to shorten it?

Comment: This is a one time cost that people incur before they setup DNS, can you clarify why you need it to be fast (out of curiosity)?

Comment: We build a platform where the user clicks: "create app" (from a template) and then "preview app" and the Browser opens and we have to tell him "Please drink a coffee until we provision your application". Some don't have the patience and move along. :(

Comment: Type=loadbalancer actually provisions a node port for the service. This should be immediate, and the user can access their app on public-ip-of-any-node-in-cluster:nodeport till the loadbalancer is provisioned. Maybe this is enough?

Comment: We will check that. But it looks a bit like a hack

Comment: Yeah unfortunately it does take a little while to create the various cloud resources required. Just pointing out that there's more than 1 way to skin that cat :)

Answer (score 2):

The delay is unfortunately just caused by latency in the Compute Engine APIs for creating the components of a load balanced service, and there's no real way to avoid it.

The Kubernetes master, when instructed to create a load balancer, has to create a static IP address, a target pool, a forwarding rule, and a firewall rule. These resources can take some time to fully initialize and be ready for use, so a wait of a minute or two is to be expected for now.