# Tuning GKE to speed up for allocating and assigning IP to new service

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to ask about how to tune up the speed of allocating and assigning IP to service that spawn by GKE.
In the normal situation, GKE will take time around 30 seconds - 1 minute for assigning IP to the new service. But when GKE spawns more than 20 services at the same time, it takes time around 4 minutes - 6 minutes. Is there any solution to solve this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34930164/12429357) by [Alex Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925481/alex-robinson), when creating a LoadBalancer service in GKE, the Compute Engine API has to create the ILB, along its target pool, forwarding rules and firewall rules.

This, combined with several LoadBalancer object creations from Kubernetes at once can cause the GCE API requests to pile up, and in your case could also throttle the calls internally due to the [GCE API requests per second](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api-rate-limits) project-wide limits being hit, for which requesting a [quota increase](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?metric=Queries%20per%20100%20seconds&_ga=2.190569835.1739195211.1606727064-1939519442.1596195909) (after checking on its [usage](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/overview)) may help if you're heavily relying on simultaneous LoadBalancer deployments.